# Android Studio multiple numbers with spinner selection

Tags: java, android, spinner, currency, multiplication

So I'm attempting to have a spinner where you select a currency to convert to from GBP, enter a value in GBP and convert to the selected currency from the spinner by pressing a button. The converted value will then appear in the textview below

[image]

Here is the following code I have in the Convert activity i'm using, the app is crashing upon trying to switch to this layout from the main menu, however it was working before i tried adding the multiplication code. Thanks in advance.

```
public class Convert extends AppCompatActivity {


final EditText currency_input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_currency_input);
final TextView answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_convert_to);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.convert);

    Spinner spinner_convert_from = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_convert_from);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.currency_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner_convert_from.setAdapter(adapter);
}



private void USD() {
    answer.setText(String.valueOf(Double.valueOf(String.valueOf(currency_input.getText()))*1.2798));
}

private void EUR() {
    answer.setText(String.valueOf(Double.valueOf(String.valueOf(currency_input.getText()))*1.14502));
}

private void AUD() {
    answer.setText(String.valueOf(Double.valueOf(String.valueOf(currency_input.getText()))*1.71911));
}

private void CAD() {
    answer.setText(String.valueOf(Double.valueOf(String.valueOf(currency_input.getText()))*1.7226));
}

private void JPY() {
    answer.setText(String.valueOf(Double.valueOf(String.valueOf(currency_input.getText()))*142.482));
}

private void CHF() {
    answer.setText(String.valueOf(Double.valueOf(String.valueOf(currency_input.getText()))* 1.24662));
}

private void CNY() {
    answer.setText(String.valueOf(Double.valueOf(String.valueOf(currency_input.getText()))* 8.7714));
}

private void KRW() {
    answer.setText(String.valueOf(Double.valueOf(String.valueOf(currency_input.getText()))*1430.8));
}

private void SEK() {
    answer.setText(String.valueOf(Double.valueOf(String.valueOf(currency_input.getText()))* 11.1187));
}


public class planOnClickListener implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos,
                               long id) {
        parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);

        if (pos == 0) {
            USD();
        } else if (pos == 1) {
            EUR();
        } else if (pos == 2) {
            AUD();
        } else if (pos == 3) {
            CAD();
        } else if (pos == 4) {
            JPY();
        } else if (pos == 5) {
            CHF();
        } else if (pos == 6) {
            CNY();
        } else if (pos == 7) {
            KRW();
        } else if (pos == 8) {
            SEK();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: If it's crashing there is a corresponding entry in Logcat (Android Monitor) Please share it

Comment: Sorry I'm quite new to Android Studio and i'm not quite sure what i'm looking for in the Logcat as there are like 1000+ messages in it when i run the app in the emulator.

Comment: Yes, it's quite a lot even in an emulator :) There is a search field, you can type in e.g. your package name to narrow down the search. Or, as you're looking for a crash report, you can toggle the level of log message (several levels from verbose to error)

Comment: So i ran the app again and searched for the class name "Convert" in the Logcat and filtered it to 'error' in the level of problem and [this](https://gyazo.com/7b55efd092d12a48d50ae9024e9a5138) is what I was getting, again not sure if this is what you are looking for and apologies in advance for not quite knowing what i'm doing.

Comment: Yes, I was looking for something like this. It seems to me that your Convert activity can't start properly, but I don't know exactly at which point the Android Runtime decided to give up. There is at least one thing in your code which looks like it might be a problem:  your declaration of the final EditText and TextView. Please try to not make them final and only set them (like ... = (EditText)findViewById(...) ) in onCreate()

Comment: Not that much clear from your log, but it seems the null pointer exception might be because you are initializing currency_input and answer variables outside of onCreate. try doing that inside your oncreate method after setting the content view

Comment: Again sorry for my limited knowledge but since declaring these within the onCreate, the 'answer' and 'currency_input' fields are not being recognised in the multiplication calculations. Does this mean I will also need to add these to the onCreate and if so how would i go about doing that. Thanks in advance again.

Comment: Sorry that's a misunderstanding, the Views should be declared as member variables but not final. You can only bind them to the id's from the xml after setContentView() has been executed, like @Ankur Jain suggested. This should take place in onCreate(). That being said, please accept FAT's answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some common errors in your codes. I have updated your code.

**Here is the working code:**

```
//Convert.java

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Convert extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText currency_input ;
    TextView answer;

    String input;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.convert);

        // Views
        currency_input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_currency_input);
        answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_convert_to);

        // Default value
        currency_input.setText("0.0");

        Spinner spinner_convert_from = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_convert_from);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.currency_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner_convert_from.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Add item selected listener
        spinner_convert_from.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos,
                                       long id) {

                // Get input text 
                input = currency_input.getText().toString();

                if (pos == 0) {
                    USD();
                } else if (pos == 1) {
                    EUR();
                } else if (pos == 2) {
                    AUD();
                } else if (pos == 3) {
                    CAD();
                } else if (pos == 4) {
                    JPY();
                } else if (pos == 5) {
                    CHF();
                } else if (pos == 6) {
                    CNY();
                } else if (pos == 7) {
                    KRW();
                } else if (pos == 8) {
                    SEK();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });

    }

    private void USD() {
        answer.setText(String.valueOf(Double.valueOf(input)*1.2798));
    }

    private void EUR() {
        answer.setText(String.valueOf(Double.valueOf(input)*1.14502));
    }

    private void AUD() {
        answer.setText(String.valueOf(Double.valueOf(input)*1.71911));
    }

    private void CAD() {
        answer.setText(String.valueOf(Double.valueOf(input)*1.7226));
    }

    private void JPY() {
        answer.setText(String.valueOf(Double.valueOf(input)*142.482));
    }

    private void CHF() {
        answer.setText(String.valueOf(Double.valueOf(input)* 1.24662));
    }

    private void CNY() {
        answer.setText(String.valueOf(Double.valueOf(input)* 8.7714));
    }

    private void KRW() {
        answer.setText(String.valueOf(Double.valueOf(input)*1430.8));
    }

    private void SEK() {
        answer.setText(String.valueOf(Double.valueOf(input)* 11.1187));
    }
}
```

**Here is your layout XML:**

```
// convert.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    tools:context="com.ferdous.stackoverflowanswer.Convert">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_convert_to"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24dp"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_convert_from"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp">

    </Spinner>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_currency_input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, really appreciate the help.

Comment: Most welcome...If my answer seems useful then mark it as right answer :)